# findViewById Returns An Error

Tags: java, android, textview

findViewById gives out an error, I think it's because it's returning null. My app is forced to close.

```
SensorManager sensorManager=null;

TextView x= null;
TextView y= null;
TextView z= null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    x= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    y= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    z= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
}
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_x="10px"
    android:layout_y="550px"
    android:text="@string/x"
    />  
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_x="100px"
    android:layout_y="550px"
    android:text="@string/y"
    />  
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_x="200px"
    android:layout_y="550px"
    android:text="@string/z"
    />
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

SOLVED!

I used the XML given by Sunny at the bottom! Thank you to all!

Comment: Are `tv1`, `tv2` and `tv3` declared properly in the main layout xml?

Comment: `Help?` <- layout? (it can also be that you did not declare this activity in your manifest)

Comment: show me your error what logcat shows and your xml layout also

Comment: I already added 3 TextViews with those IDs in XML. Sorry, but how do I see the LogCat?

Comment: The logcat is something you must use before even thinking programming and ask question. Without it, you are totally blind on your code. To display: add view -> Logcat

Comment: to display the logcat click the menu : Window -> Show View -> and then choose logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes above code working fine and xml file should be like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
 <TextView 
 android:id="@+id/tv1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
 <TextView 
  android:id="@+id/tv2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
  <TextView>
 android:id="@+id/tv3"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you understand it now ,and you have deleted your post :) , you should let it so others can get informations from it :)

Comment: I tried to use this as my XML, and it worked! Thank you so much, sir!

Answer (score 2):

<s>That's simple.... tv* is not in your layout!</s>

Please post the layout, I am 100% sure it doesn't contain:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv2"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv3"/>
```

Please also learn how to get a logcat before going further in android development! ;-)

### **Window -> Show View -> Logcat**

Comment: I for got to post that I have already added an XML before posting, i'll edit it again. :D

Answer (score 0):

**First :** Verify that your `TextView` Are present on your layout : `main.xml` :

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" .../>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv2" .../>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv3" .../>
```

**Second :** reBuild your project by following this steps : **Project ==> Clean ==> Select your project and click OK .**

Answer (score 0):

yes that problem and if with xml is not done then 
You import android.R;
so that it will give error if xml you have
remove that 
and import PACKAGENAME.R;

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is :

`findViewById()` will search for the TextViews in the View hierarchy established by `setContentView(R.layout.main)`. So if the TextViews aren't in main.xml you will get a null